# What could possibly go wrong adopting this trivial class to handle optional values?

Tags: c++, class, templates, stl, option-type

In certain applications I am stuck with a c++98 compiler.
I like the idea to handle certain errors returning an optional, so I crafted this trivial class to handle them:

```
template<class T> class Optional
{
 public:
    Optional<T>() : i_Assigned(false) {}
    explicit Optional<T>(const T& v) : i_Value(v), i_Assigned(true) {}

    bool assigned() const { return i_Assigned; }
    const T& value() const { if(!i_Assigned) throw std::runtime_error("Optional value not assigned!"); return i_Value; }

    Optional<T>& operator=(const T& v) { i_Value=v; i_Assigned=true; return *this; }

 private:
    T i_Value;
    bool i_Assigned;
};
```

I'm satisfied with my tests so far and I'm about to use it in my production code:

```
Optional<double> val = funct_returning_optional();
if( val.assigned() ) use(val.value());
else something_went_wrong();
```

...But its extreme simplicity makes me wonder, what I'm missing? Why the standard implementation is so complex? What could possibly go wrong by adopting my self made abomination?

Comment: Doesnt seem to handle move only types (and possibly other things). You might be on C++98 but the standard one is C++17 so it would.

Comment: You don't handle the corner cases of `optional`. As already mentioned you don't handle move-only, but more importantly, you don't handle non-default constructible `T`. The purpose of optional is to not have to construct anything in case the optional is empty, which is not what you have here.

Comment: @Borgleader yes, but no way to move things in my old compiler :-)

Comment: @Holt exactly, now I understand. Since I plan to use it with PODs, I kind of like that a non default constructible class would cause a compiler error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One basic issue with your implementation is that it isn't able to accommodate types that lack a default constructor. Similarly, if the default constructor of `T` has any side effects, those side effects will occur when `Optional<T>` is constructed. The `std::optional<T>` is not supposed to have any side effects when default-constructed (in fact, the default constructor is `constexpr`).

The way `std::optional` handles this is to not have a member of type `T`, but instead a member that is a union, one of whose elements has type `T`:

```
template <class T>
class optional {
    union Storage {
        T t;
        char c;
        Storage() : c(0) {}
    } storage;
    bool has_value;
  public:
    optional() : has_value(false) {}
};
```

When the optional object is default-constructed, the `storage.c` member is initialized, and there is no `T` object yet, so no constructor needs to be called for `T`.

This immediately complicates the rest of the implementation. Whenever the optional goes from having a `T` to not having a `T` (which can happen when it is destroyed, reset, or assigned from an empty optional), the destructor must be explicitly called on `storage.t`. Whenever it goes from not having a `T` to having a `T` (which can happen when it is copy constructed from a non-empty optional, assigned from a `T`, or assigned from a non-empty optional), placement new must be used to start the lifetime of `storage.t`.

The C++17 `optional` also has certain other key requirements. I assume you already know about move constructors and move assignment operators. What really complicates things, though, is the requirement for `std::optional<T>` to have a trivial copy constructor, copy assignment operator, move constructor, move assignment operator, or destructor whenever the corresponding member of `T` is trivial. In C++17, the only way to implement this requirement is to have `optional<T>` pull in its special member functions from internal base classes, where one version of the base class handles the trivial case by using the implicitly defined function, and another version handles the nontrivial case with a user-provided function. This is the main reason why the standard library implementations are so long.

Comment: Very clear, now I understand. I'll be safe to use my Optional just with plain old data types or very simple classes, unfortunately this constraint will be just a comment: if I had concepts available, I'd be using std::optional